# How to fix "400 - Bad Request" in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have Spring application built in Maven, When I am trying to submit the form to the database it is throwing 400 - Bad request error. I have mapped data through Entity Class. The console window also not displaying any error.

Controller Class:

```
@PostMapping("/saveClient")
    public String saveClients(@ModelAttribute("client") Clients theClients) {

        clientService.saveClient(theClients);

        return "redirect:/clients/list";
    }
```

DAO Class:

```
@Override
    public void saveClient(Clients theClients) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theClients);

    }
```

JSP File:

```
<form:form name="NewClient" action="saveClient" modelAttribute="client" method="POST"
onSubmit="return(validate());">

<form:hidden path="id" />

<div class="form-group">
   <label>First Name:</label>
   <form:input type="text" path="firstName" placeholder="First Name"  id="firstName"  class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Last Name:</label>
   <form:input type="text" path="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName"  class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Domain:</label>
    <form:select path="domain" class="form-control">
         <form:option value="NONE" label="Select" />
         <form:options items="${domainList}" id="proDomain" />
    </form:select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Start Date:</label>
    <form:input type="date" path="startDate" id="projectBeginingDate"
                                    required="required" class="form-control"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </form:form>
```

Error:

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
Apache Tomcat/9.0.16
```

Comment: Your server has console logs that will explain what happened.

Comment: There are no warning messages. The only warnings are related to JDK I guess that won't relate to my 400 error.

Comment: `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/VIVEK/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/solution/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)`

Comment: `WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release`

Comment: The `illegal reflective access` bits are completely ordinary for applications running on Java 9+. Try turning up your `org.springframework.web` logger to DEBUG.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? Did you add `@EnableWebMvc`?

Comment: Yes, I have that annotation in my application.